# SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA is null

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement quick search box for my app. I have created a suggestions table with all required columns but the system fails to pass the data in `SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA` with the intent from Search Dialog. Why?

```
if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {
    Bundle data = intent.getExtras();
    Set<String> SS = data.keySet();
    Log.d(Tag.getTag(this), ("data :" + intent.getData() + " , " + SS.toString() ));
};
```

And it gives the following output:

```
12-11 21:27:11.686: D/com.simple.search.com.simple.search.SimpleSearch(5287):
data :null , [user_query]
```